# Getting force close when selecting contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

i have made an app in which i want the user to select contacts from the Contacts and display the selected contact name in the list.So for that i have used intent.But when ever the user selects the contact the app force closes.??

Code

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                if (number.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
                    phones.moveToFirst();
                    String contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    contacts.add(contactNumber);
                    contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(getActivity(), contacts);
                    lvContact.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);


                }
            }
```

Logcat

```
07-31 12:52:07.469  29788-29788/example.com.pocketdocs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/2636 }} to activity {example.com.pocketdocs/example.com.pocketdocs.MainActivity.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3205)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
            at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
            at example.com.pocketdocs.Group.CreatNewGroup.onActivityResult(CreatNewGroup.java:74)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5196)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3205)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I only when the user to see the contacts which are having numbers,i dnt want fb and google contacts.

Comment: what is at line no 74 of CreatNewGroup

Comment: String contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

Answer (score 1):

I believe your phones cursor is empty. Try checking with:

```
if(phones.moveToFirst()) {
        String contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        contacts.add(contactNumber);
        contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(getActivity(), contacts);
        lvContact.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);
}
```